Command not found: docker-compose after docker 4.32.0 update
After updating Docker on my mac to 4.32.0, docker-compose seems to not work anymore. Everything with docker works fine, all the docker commands work fine. I can also use docker run to start any container. However, docker-compsoe and all its commands don't seem to work.
What could be issue? Could it be that docker-compose needs to be separately installed, or any configuration that needs to be done? Or is it deprecated?

docker-compose (with a dash) is version 1 of compose and is outdated. It has been moved to a docker plugin and the command is now docker compose (without a dash). Try that.

Docker version: 4.32.0 need to remove the dash from docker-compose to docker compose
$ docker compose up --build

or
$ docker compose up -d

If not work, you can try this: 
Docker > Settings > Advanced > select User then Apply and Restart

and use docker compose
 - Hope it will work.
On my system macOS 14.5 & Docker 4.32.0 
it's work on default docker settings (Docker > Settings > Advanced > System)
 - using docker compose
 
Also in the compose file docker-compose.yml if you are using version: 'x.y'
 you will get this warning version is obsolete
 need to remove the first line (version: 'x.y') of the file, it’s now deprecated.

Why they couldn't add a warning when running docker-compose i have no idea.

Thank you for this, I also spend a good 10 mins trying to figure this out.

I reinstalled the docker desktop and tried manually creating shell path links, but then I saw this. Why on earth didn't they add a big warning message with flashing lights attached to it - that's a massive breaking change lol

I had this same problem too, it appears this was a bug in the update for Docker-Desktop and will be rectified by version 4.33
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/7345#issuecomment-2232257396
In the link above they give this as a workaround:
sudo ln -sf /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/cli-plugins/docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

thanks. There's another workaround that worked for me. Instead of using docker-compose (with a dash), I could just use docker compose without dash and everything works like before. (as mentioned in the comments of the question).

Adding the solution that helped me:
In your Docker Desktop app click the settings cog and navigate to the Advanced tab. Then, enable the following checkboxes:
Allow the default Docker socket to be used (requires password)
Allow privileged port mapping (requires password)

Click apply and restart your Docker Desktop instance.
As a sidenote, I read somewhere else that even if those settings were turned on before the Docker Desktop update they need to be reapplied, so if they were already on, turn them off, apply changes and then turn them on and reapply the changes.
